# variable returns undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, console

I'm working on a function for a canvas that clears the canvas, then redraws all of the static elements. In order to do this, I'm keeping all of the canvas elements in an array, and then telling my function, `canvRD();`, to omit certain elements from the redraw, depending on whether they are in hidden or in mid-animation. To make sure it worked and returned the correct values, I tried the function with only integers in the elements array. If the element is not omitted, `canvRD();` should log `"Success" + i`. (`i` is the variable that selects the element) However, it instead logs `Success` and then adds in `[object Undefined]`

Here is my code:

```
var elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function canvRD(omitAnim, omitHid){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mathCanv.width, mathCanv.height);
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (!(omitAnim.includes(i)||omitHid.includes(i))) {
      console.log("Success " + toString(i));
    }
  }
}
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Since we don't see the call it could be as simple as you're passing in data of the wrong type.

Comment: You are calling `global.toString` without the `global` part, so there's no `this` hence `undefined`. Use `String(i)` instead (or just let javascript do its magic and cast it to string for you).

Comment: Thank @MinusFour, that worked!

Comment: You don't need `String` or `toString` `console.log("Success " + i)` works fine.